InnerHtml is not display on Screen
`
I am working on a web project using HTML and Bootstrap, but my content is not displaying in the browser.Here is my code:
`

    let str = ""
    for (let item of r.articles) {
      str = str + `
          <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="${item.urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${item.description}</p>
        <a href="${item.url}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More..</a>
      </div>
    </div>
      `
    }
    console.log(str)
    content.innerHtml = str

  }

enter image description here
`When I open this file in my browser, the card is normal bootstrap card , and no content is displayed. I have verified the following:
The file is saved with a .html extension.
The file is being opened directly in the browser (Chrome, Firefox).
There are no errors in the browser console.
And if I log string then it will be display in The Console as Following:`
 <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/0aae/live/162c92f0-233a-11ef-94ce-2524c2e905df.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Women better at sport during period, study suggests</h5>
        <p class="card-text">It could explain why women playing contact sports appear injury prone between ovulation and menstruation.</p>
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cl446z20mvjo" class="btn btn-primary">Read More..</a>
      </div>
    </div>


Plese Help me To Fixed These Error !
I have tried various approach like i have try it on Replit But same issue will be there.

It's not really clear what you're doing. It sounds like you're creating an HTML file using express, and then saving it locally, and then trying to open it in your browser, is that right? Also, your question is missing some vital code: what is r.articles, for example.

What is content and when does this code execute?

According to my understanding, you're doing all the code inside HTML file. and you are using script tag inside it(?)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>News Cards</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="content" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <!-- Cards will be inserted here by JavaScript -->
</div>

<script>
  // Example data
  const r = {
    articles: [
      {
        urlToImage: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/0aae/live/162c92f0-233a-11ef-94ce-2524c2e905df.jpg',
        title: 'Women better at sport during period, study suggests',
        description: 'It could explain why women playing contact sports appear injury prone between ovulation and menstruation.',
        url: 'https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cl446z20mvjo'
      },
       {
        urlToImage: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/0aae/live/162c92f0-233a-11ef-94ce-2524c2e905df.jpg',
        title: 'Women better at sport during period, study suggests',
        description: 'It could explain why women playing contact sports appear injury prone between ovulation and menstruation.',
        url: 'https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cl446z20mvjo'
      }
      // Add more articles here
    ]
  };

  let str = "";
  for (let item of r.articles) {
    str += `
      <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="${item.urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="Error">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">${item.description}</p>
          <a href="${item.url}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More..</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  console.log(str);
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = str;
</script>

</body>
</html>



Here I have added one div and given it id of name content,and then I used getElementById method to display everything propelry. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Don't guess. If the question is unclear, comment and ask for clarification. Don't answer.
